# how to conrol html attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `img` element on my web page and it has `data-mobil` and `data-tablet` attribute when I resize window my image src is chancing with `data-mobil` or `data-table` but if my image has not any attribute `data-mobil` or `data-table` then on responsive my img hasn't be appear on responsive how to do that.

```js
function makeResize(){
  var imageSrc = $(".myDiv img");
  if($(window).width() <=768 && $(window).width()>480){
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key,value){
      $(value).attr('src',$(value).data('tablet'));
    });
  }else if($(window).width() <=480 ) {
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key,value){
      $(value).attr('src',$(value).data('mobil'));
    });
  }else{
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key,value){
      $(value).attr('src',$(value).data('src'));
    });
  }
}
   

$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $(window).resize(function(){
        makeResize();
    });
    makeResize();
});
```

```css
.myDiv{width:900px}
.myDiv img{ display:block;margin:20px;width:100%;}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="myDiv">
    
     <img  src="http://www.slidesjs.com/img/example-slide-350-2.jpg" data-tablet="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains_wide.jpg" data-mobil="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-23/data1/images/landscape1344620.jpg">
    
     <img  src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords_wide.jpg" data-tablet="http://semtasoft.com/wp-content/gallery/semtasoft/Slide-img-4.jpg" data-mobil="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-0xYI1ZJjncM/U0eM2WjhLBI/AAAAAAAAIRk/ytNDG8Nf1x4/s1600/slide-img-1.jpg">
    
    
    
     <img  src="http://hdimagesnew.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/New-Wallpapers-HD.jpg" data-mobil="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-0xYI1ZJjncM/U0eM2WjhLBI/AAAAAAAAIRk/ytNDG8Nf1x4/s1600/slide-img-1.jpg">
        
     <img  src="http://csgowallpapers.com/assets/images/original/mossawi_697490225546_20161227125412_701766109559.png" data-tablet="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-0xYI1ZJjncM/U0eM2WjhLBI/AAAAAAAAIRk/ytNDG8Nf1x4/s1600/slide-img-1.jpg">
    
        <img  src="http://csgowallpapers.com/assets/images/original/mossawi_521575293969_20170108191041_920035389717.png">
    
    </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, what you wanna do when you don't have any `data-*` attributes or its values for any image? You want to keep the original one?

Comment: no I want to remove img element which has no data-*.for example if my image has not data-mobil I want to remove my image on mobil if my image has not data-tablet I want to remove my image on tablet but if my screen is wide (desktop) I want to keep my image

Comment: `remove` or `hide`?

Comment: sorry I want to hide it my english is not enough to tell something :)

Comment: Nevermind.. Language is not a problem if you clarify things.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check whether the value of respective `data-*` attribute is `undefined` and then `hide/show` accordingly along with changing `src` attribute on `show`.

Here's your updated snippet.

```js
function makeResize() {
  var imageSrc = $(".myDiv img");
  if ($(window).width() <= 768 && $(window).width() > 480) {
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key, value) {
      if ($(value).data('tablet') == undefined)
        $(value).hide();
      else {
        $(value).attr('src', $(value).data('tablet'));
        $(value).show();
      }
    });
  } else if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key, value) {
      if ($(value).data('mobil') == undefined) {
        $(value).hide();
      } else {
        $(value).attr('src', $(value).data('mobil'));
        $(value).show();
      }
    });
  } else {
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key, value) {
      $(value).attr('src', $(value).data('src'));
    });
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    makeResize();
  });
  makeResize();
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 900px
}
.myDiv img {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="myDiv">

    <img src="http://www.slidesjs.com/img/example-slide-350-2.jpg" data-tablet="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains_wide.jpg" data-mobil="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-23/data1/images/landscape1344620.jpg">

    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords_wide.jpg" data-tablet="http://semtasoft.com/wp-content/gallery/semtasoft/Slide-img-4.jpg" data-mobil="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-0xYI1ZJjncM/U0eM2WjhLBI/AAAAAAAAIRk/ytNDG8Nf1x4/s1600/slide-img-1.jpg">



    <img src="http://hdimagesnew.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/New-Wallpapers-HD.jpg" data-mobil="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-0xYI1ZJjncM/U0eM2WjhLBI/AAAAAAAAIRk/ytNDG8Nf1x4/s1600/slide-img-1.jpg">

    <img src="http://csgowallpapers.com/assets/images/original/mossawi_697490225546_20161227125412_701766109559.png" data-tablet="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-0xYI1ZJjncM/U0eM2WjhLBI/AAAAAAAAIRk/ytNDG8Nf1x4/s1600/slide-img-1.jpg">

    <img src="http://csgowallpapers.com/assets/images/original/mossawi_521575293969_20170108191041_920035389717.png">

  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yes it's exactly as I want but when I resize screen to wide my image hasn't appear it just hide on responsive can you help for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just check `img data` with simple condition. You can use following code for this

```
function makeResize(){
  var imageSrc = $(".myDiv img");
  if($(window).width() <=768 && $(window).width()>480){
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key,value){
      if($(value).data('tablet') == undefined || $(value).data('tablet') == '' || $(value).data('tablet') == null) {
        // no src change
      } else {
        $(value).attr('src',$(value).data('tablet'));
      }     

    });
  }else if($(window).width() <=480 ) {
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key,value){
      if($(value).data('mobil') == undefined || $(value).data('mobil') == '' || $(value).data('mobil') == null) {
        // no src change
      } else {
        $(value).attr('src',$(value).data('mobil'));
      } 
    });
  }else{
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key,value){
       if($(value).data('src') == undefined || $(value).data('src') == '' || $(value).data('src') == null) {
        // no src change
      } else {
        $(value).attr('src',$(value).data('src'));
      } 
    });
  }
}
```